# why i got these errors my data is saved to database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

i set values and inserted to database but i got the following errors in logcat.why

```
03-25 17:41:23.802: E/SQLiteDatabase(10095): Error inserting devicename=iname alarm=ON uuid=00000000-5f53-54ae-5f53-54ae00000000 light=ON
03-25 17:41:23.802: E/SQLiteDatabase(10095): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: column uuid is not unique (code 19)
03-25 17:41:23.802: E/SQLiteDatabase(10095):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
03-25 17:41:23.802: E/SQLiteDatabase(10095):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:782)
03-25 17:41:23.802: E/SQLiteDatabase(10095):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
03-25 17:41:23.802: E/SQLiteDatabase(10095):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
03-25 17:41:23.802: E/SQLiteDatabase(10095):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
03-25 17:41:23.802: E/SQLiteDatabase(10095):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
03-25 17:41:23.802: E/SQLiteDatabase(10095):    at com.iname.bpowerbank.DataBaseAdapter.insertData(DataBaseAdapter.java:97)
03-25 17:41:23.802: E/SQLiteDatabase(10095):    at com.iname.bpowerbank.EditPreview.onCreate(EditPreview.java:68)
03-25 17:41:23.802: E/SQLiteDatabase(10095):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
03-25 17:41:23.802: E/SQLiteDatabase(10095):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-25 17:41:23.802: E/SQLiteDatabase(10095):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
03-25 17:41:23.802: E/SQLiteDatabase(10095):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-25 17:41:23.802: E/SQLiteDatabase(10095):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-25 17:41:23.802: E/SQLiteDatabase(10095):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-25 17:41:23.802: E/SQLiteDatabase(10095):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-25 17:41:23.802: E/SQLiteDatabase(10095):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-25 17:41:23.802: E/SQLiteDatabase(10095):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-25 17:41:23.802: E/SQLiteDatabase(10095):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 17:41:23.802: E/SQLiteDatabase(10095):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-25 17:41:23.802: E/SQLiteDatabase(10095):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-25 17:41:23.802: E/SQLiteDatabase(10095):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-25 17:41:23.802: E/SQLiteDatabase(10095):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You're trying to insert a value to the `uuid` column while the table already has a row with such value in that column, and the column has an `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` constraint.

Comment: ok then how to insert only once.i had three activities. my app is like this in first activity i had done to scan and get the list of devices and check if database in not null get those values.and it post those values(name,uuid,toggle values on ,off)to second activity.

Comment: in second activity i did like to retrive the values from first and to perform some actions using those values.in this page only i added the settings menu(like same as bluetooth device has like to rename,it states like light,alarm to toggle).so when settings menu is clicked it takes to the third class.in this third class i had done database to insert values(these values i get from second activity)and for update i wrote update in database adapter.its fine when i back pressed it is saving to database.but when i move to first activity only it is saving if move to second activity it is not why?

Answer (score 0):

You violated a constraint on your uuid column. It must be unique. Insert always unique values.

Check [this](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html) post to see sqlite error descriptions

Yours is #19.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible fixes,

```
1. Remove UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY property for the column "uuid"
```

or

```
2. use INSERT OR REPLACE INTO table_name (UUID,name) VALUES ('uuid_value','name_value')
```

Comment: then it i will have another record of same uuid na.it should not have like that.

Comment: If your using INSERT OR REPLACE you will not have duplicate UUID. My 2nd suggestion will fix your issue na?

Comment: uuid is unique(for bluetooth device it has only one uuid and i am using list of devices.)and when i rerun it will re insert na

Comment: Then Try following,
1. Change uuid as PRIMARY (not unique)
2. use INSERT OR REPLACE (instead of simple insert)

I think you are not mentioned primary key while create table in sqlite. so rowid is automatically created as primary key in sqlite.

follow the above two steps that will helps you to eliminate duplicate value as well as this issue.